# Permission Set - Enabling Access not working

Tags: permissions, profile, permission-sets

We have two profiles P1 & P2.

P1 has the "Transfer Record" permission enabled whereas P2 does not.
But we have created a new permission set in which we added users who have P2 profile and enabled the access to "edit" Opportunity Owner field in it.

We expected this permission set will allow users (P2 profile) to change the Opportunity Owner (aka Transfering ownership to themselves) but this is not happening.

They are getting Insufficient Privileges error when they click on "Change" hyperlink next to Opportunity Owner field.

I assumed that Permission Set can be used to bypass the existing restrictions.

Am I not right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transfer ownership is not same as just edit permission on the field .

We are trying to change the owner here which means unless user has access to the record you will receive this kind of error.

Consider looking OWD for the object and determine sharing rules .Try to provide access to share the record rather than just edit field .When you give modify all the other user will be able to transfer the record .

So try giving Modify all ,but with Modify all user will gain lot of permission access as well so be cautious on how your business wants sharing access for that record .